# How to remove GUI on Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments

I wan't command line only server machine. So, I wish to remover GUI from server, which was installed automatically during upgrade.

Simultaneously, I don't want to remove `X` because I still wish to be able to run `X Window` applications on `VNC` or `XServer`.

How to do that?

**UPDATE**

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntustudio-desktop
```

didn't help

**UPDATE 2**

Changing

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash console=tty1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

in `etc/default/grub` didn't help (it only affected graphics during boot phase)

**UPDATE 3**

Changing to

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=3
```

in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` didn't help.

**UPDATE 4**

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions
ubuntustudio.desktop  xfce.desktop
```

**UPDATE 5**

Adding "manual" to `lightdm.override`

```
$ cat /etc/init/lightdm.override
manual
```

didn't help, although stopping `lightdm` service

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

closes desktop. How to make this service never run?

**UPDATE 6**

```
$ sudo update-rc.d lightdm disable
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

didn't help

**SOLUTION**

```
systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

helped, thanks @steeldriver

Comment: What GUI was installed, exactly? What are the contents of `/usr/share/xsessions`?

Comment: See my update 4 pls!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer rather than a part of the question.

Comment: It looks like L. D. James' answer below (http://askubuntu.com/a/823501/593945) is correct, so please accept it.

Comment: I would notice that this *disable* but do not remove GUI, which can be reenabled with: systemctl enable lightdm.service or started once with systemctl start lightdm.service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the tested comments discussion this is done use `systemd` disable argument:

```
$ systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

Comment: What is `lightdm.conf` and how can it help?

Comment: "manual" way didn't work

Comment: @Dims You're right.  I did research and gave you the results that was reported working.  I just tested some of the steps and find Ubuntu apparently is not using any of it's published methods for disabling the GUI.  I'll continue to research how to disable it and update my answer with a working solution for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Incredible. They are making less and less controllable linux.

Comment: @Dims Yes.  It appears the changes are happening faster than the Documentation can keep up.

Comment: 16.04 uses `systemd` rather than `upstart` - the equivalent command (I think) would be `sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service` or more generally `sudo systemctl disable display-manager.service` which should work regardless of which DM is providing the service.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks!  It appears to be working.  I'm seeing some problems that I'm trying to figure out.  The login doesn't come up, but it appears to go to the graphic console without the graphics.  It doesn't  boot to a visible tty (tty1).

Comment: @Dims I'm making progress with the help of stealdriver.  I'll update the answer when it appears to work perfect.  Look at stealdriver's` systemctl` command.  The second one doesn't work but the first one might closer fit your objective.

Comment: @Dims Great! Consider checking it resolved and others easier find a solution that works.  Thanks for the acknowledgement.

Comment: @Dims Reviewing your updated message, I guess I misunderstood your comment.  I thought you were acknowledging this answer (when I got the notification in this answer section).

Comment: Downvote because this does not *remove* (uninstall) the graphical environment. It merely disables it.